# cherrypick types in typescript when calling an external library function

Tags: typescript, chakra-ui

I am trying to use a helper function from a library with a strict type in typescript but I can't seem to get it to work.

For instance, the following code from chakraui.

```
export interface BaseBreakpointConfig {
  sm: string
  md: string
  lg: string
  xl: string
  "2xl"?: string
  [key: string]: string | undefined
}

export type Breakpoints<T> = T & { base: "0em" }

export const createBreakpoints = <T extends BaseBreakpointConfig>(
  config: T,
): Breakpoints<T> => {
  warn({
    condition: true,
    message: [
      `[chakra-ui]: createBreakpoints(...) will be deprecated pretty soon`,
      `simply pass the breakpoints as an object. Remove the createBreakpoint(..) call`,
    ].join(""),
  })
  return { base: "0em", ...config }
}
```

And I want to call the `createBreakpoints` function without supplying all the keys, how would I do that? Is that possible?

I tried using the `Pick` utility but that didn't help.

```
type Breakpoints = Pick<BaseBreakpointConfig, 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'>

const breakpoints = createBreakPoints<Breakpoints>({
  sm: "...",
  md: "...",
  lg: "..."
});
```

I got the `Property "xl" is missing in type "Breakpoints" but required in type BaseBreakpointConfig` error

Comment: If you can not change the definition of `createBreakpoints` then you have to provide all mandatory keys of `BaseBreakpointConfig`. No way around that other than bypassing the type system with `as any`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), which returns a type where every property of `Type` is optional, we can make `T` extend `Partial<BaseBreakpointConfig>`. This will make `createBreakpoints()` accept arguments with types are subsets of `BaseBreakpointConfig`, like `Pick<BaseBreakpointConfig, 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'>`:

```
export const createBreakpoints = <T extends Partial<BaseBreakpointConfig>>(
  config: T,
): Breakpoints<T> => {
  // ...
};

const breakpoints = createBreakpoints<Pick<BaseBreakpointConfig, 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg'>>({
  sm: "...",
  md: "...",
  lg: "..."
}); // works
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=45&pln=12&pc=53#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIUwGdh8phMBrSZGAYQiXQQHM4BvAWACg44iAtgC5+MKMhY8+AgCYiiYiVLgAbFvMVJJvOCBUbxW5QCIATHuMB+A0p0BtSsACeNrQF1XbAD5wArkhlgZiRgGR4AXx4eUEhYOBgnMDwyCmoIWiIAHgAVAD44AF44bLgAMg44ACNiYBFjAAZgAWM4SO5o8Gh4bEYFOGxyTFQUqhoUIkK4HLhQVACJgAVMWARMFUzCEhG02gYmVlzcgAplHv31YoAaHgBKEW2xmCy8wvyuHQB3ZaQj974+M4yBAwBCMERiXzAa46aTAIhETAsWpwOzKf5wAAGdmwAAsqFBMABaXwIDz9QbDQY7cZHAB09JucA+CBUKiqeECYHI2CGoTgXOAMAS-AgjAx0PRfAxRAQAjAKic-OIExgOLwlSpjwmxDgmCQcAglQAVsBsDBaXAAEpNCAANzwqrwAwolNSjzptMZPNZ4rRcDctKN6R+xmMNwlrRuynIMF8UH17CqNTqjWalzg9NpZ2YbDabR4Zz6Grdwaek2dvIepayCwQ2EoGxqVd2jBz6YA5IJ23AfO3ZN3e2p24dfspBHVM8YI7IJ-Sp8o1LPacYIjcANxAA)

Comment: I cannot change the function definition

Comment: @Toxnyc oh sorry I guess I didn't read the question thoroughly enough. I'm not sure it's possible in that case  Your only hope would be to pass the parameter `as any`.